# .htaccess re-direct of traffic to index.php only

Tags: .htaccess

I need to re-direct all traffic coming to domain.com/index.php to domain.com/forum/index.php

**Example**:

> Original request: 
>  domain.com/index.php?topic=11841.0
>
> Re-direct to:
>  domain.com/forum/index.php?topic=11841.0

Also

> Original request: 
>  domain.com/index.php/board,200.0.html
>
> Re-direct to:
>  domain.com/forum/index.php/board,200.0.html

But only traffic that is coming to index.php with a query string must be redirected. All other traffic to domain.com must not be redirected, and traffic to index.php without a query string should also not be re-directed.

We just moved a forum that resided on the root of the domain to a subfolder. The root of the domain now has a Wordpress installation, but we want all old forum discussion links to be re-directed to its new subfolder.

TIA

Comment: this request domain.com/forum/index.php/board,200.0.html should go to  domain.com/index.php/board,200.0.html internally or not?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `/index.php/*` to `/fourm/index.php/*` you can use the following Rule in your `/root/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /fourm/index.php/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect all requests including `query string` and `path info` from `/index.php` to `/fourm/index.php` . If you want to redirect the url only when there is a query string , use the following Rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if query string is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
# redirect "/index.php" to "/forum/index.php
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /forum/index.php [L,R]
```

The Rule above will redirect `/index.php?queryString` to `/fourm/index.php?queryString` .